# Multiple(Less no.) Insert into 3 column table vs Storing in Single Column Php-Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, scalability

I am really confused on which approach will be better. I have a situation where there is 3 table's called `category`,`question`,`question_answer`.
Columns for these tables are as follows:

**Category**

`id` - integer

`name` - string

**Question**

`id` - integer

`category_id` - integer

`question_number` - integer

`question` - string

**Question_Answer (Option 1)**

`id` - integer

`question_id` - integer

`user_id` - integer

`answer` - integer

**Question_Answer (Option 2)**

`id` - integer

`category_id` - integer

`user_id` - integer

`answer` - JSON String({"question_no": "answer"..})

I am designing a Q&A App where there will be many categories and each category will have maximum of 15 questions each of them having only integer as answer(No decimal). No. of questions in each may vary but will be limited to 15. I have to make the third table `question_answer` which should be scalable and efficient. Now, the user who answers in any one category have to solve all the questions, there is no partial answering. Which option will be better in terms of scalability Option 1 or Option 2.
If you need any more information please let me know in comments. The number of categories will be very huge and there will be frequent updates on answers by users.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use option 1 , with answer field where user's answer will be stored.Do not store json string or else just plain text.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is for storing stuff that you won't need to filter on, nor sort on.

In your example, if you need to find all the answers to a particular question, then have `question_no` as a separate column with an index on it.